# How to run 'msmtp' mail command in PHP system()?

Tags: php, shell, system, msmtp

My server don't have 'postfix' to send mails from 'sendmail'.

Instead, I use 'msmtp' and 's-nail' shell commands.

It works well from interactive shell ('bash').

I try to send mail from PHP, but I don't receive any, and have no output nor error:

```
<?php

$mess = 'foobar';
$to = 'me@mail.org';
$subject = 'test';
//mail($to,$subject,$mess); doesn't work
$out = system("echo $mess | /usr/bin/s-nail -v -s $subject $to");
echo $out;
?>
```

Any help?

If I run the script like this :

```
# php script.php
```

it works.

But when called from web, it doesn't work

Comment: when  YOU run it, do you run it with the web user?

Comment: Was as user root =) Dirty; bad, shame ^^

Comment: So the issue is most likely the diff in permissions between your manual run as root, and the perms of the web user..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution there: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Msmtp#Miscellaneous

In 'php.ini':

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/bin/msmtp -C /etc/msmtprc -t"
```

In `/etc/mail.rc`:

```
set mta=/usr/bin/msmtp
```

In PHP script, now `mail()` run properly.

---

If you have the package `msmtp-mta` like Debian/Ubuntu, things are more simple. It enable port 25 to listen on localhost as a `MTA`